# Three.js duplicates objects shape but uses new color with ColladaLoader and STLLoader

Tags: javascript, three.js, stl, collada

I need to load collada and STL models stored in files to the same scene. I do this with [three.js](https://threejs.org/) framework with a standard [`ColladaLoader()`](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html) and [`STLLoader()`](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_stl.html) like in the linked examples.

The first object appears correctly, but the second repeats its shape in the color of the second object.

I don't understand why. Where can be the problem?

UPD

```
    var sloader = new STLLoader();
    sloader.load( 'models/m1.stl', function ( geometry ) {
    var meshMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xAAAAAA, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200 } );
    if ( geometry.hasColors ) {
      meshMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { opacity: geometry.alpha, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } );
    }

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, meshMaterial );

    mesh.castShadow = true;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;

    scene.add( mesh );

  });


  var tmploader = new ColladaLoader();
  tmploader.load('models/m2.dae',

      function (geometry) {
        var robot = geometry.scene;

        var meshMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

        robot.traverse(function(child) {
          if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            child.material = meshMaterial;
          }
        });

        //robot = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, meshMaterial );

        scene.add(robot);
      });

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 2000 );
  camera.position.set( -10, 10, -10);
  camera.lookAt( 0, 3, 0 );

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // lights
  var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040, 1.0 ); // soft white light
  scene.add( light );

  var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1.0 );
  directionalLight.position.set( 1, 1, -1 ).normalize();
  scene.add( directionalLight );

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post some code to give an idea of what is happening. Most likely you are not assigning a material to the object - in that case three.js assigns a `MeshBasicMaterial` with a random hue.

Comment: I don't understand this part of your question: "but the second repeats its shape in the color of the second object". Are you saying that the second object is identical to the first? Can you please show some code of how you used the two loaders to get your models?

Comment: @TheJim01, I add the code

Comment: @HoboJoe, I assign material to both loaded objects, but this does't help.

Comment: I was able to merge the Collada and STL loader examples (https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html & https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_stl.html), and it seemed to work as expected (both models loaded with the correct materials). Could you create a minimal working example (using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)) that replicates the problem you're seeing?